# Filling data into .jasper file from a java program

Tags: java, hibernate, jasper-reports

Below is my bean class used for creating table and mappings using hibernate :

```
package org.jasperreports.entitiy;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity(name="User_table")  
public class User {
 @Id  
 private int userId;  
 @Column(name="User_Name")  
 private String userName;  
 private  String userMessage;  

 public int getUserId() {  
  return userId;  
 }  
 public void setUserId(int userId) {  
  this.userId = userId;  
 }  
 public String getUserName() {  
  return userName;  
 }  
 public void setUserName(String userName) {  
  this.userName = userName;  
 }  
 public String getUserMessage() {  
  return userMessage;  
 }  
 public void setUserMessage(String userMessage) {  
  this.userMessage = userMessage;  
 }
```

}

This will create a table in the database named user_table

Below is my class that I am using to generate a report

```
public class JasperReportTest {
Connection conn = null;
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
String dbName = "jaspersoft";
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String userName = "root";
String password = "root";
String fileName = "C://JasperSoft/MyReports/sample2.jasper";
String outFileNamePDF = "C://JasperSoft/MyReports/sample2.pdf";

public JasperReportTest() {
    super();
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void generateReport(HashMap hm) {
    try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager
                .getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
        System.out.println("Connected to the database");
        System.out.println("Filling report...");
        // used for synchronization between database and source file.
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(fileName, hm, conn);
        System.out.println(conn);
        // define and initialize jasperreport engine's exporter for .pdf
        JRExporter exporter = new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter();
        // parameter used for the destined file.

        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,
                outFileNamePDF);
        // export to .pdf
        exporter.exportReport();


        System.out.println("Created file: " + outFileNamePDF);
        System.out.println("Done!");
        conn.close();
    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
      Configuration configuration=new Configuration();  
      configuration.configure();  
      ServiceRegistry sr= new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();  
      SessionFactory sf=configuration.buildSessionFactory(sr);  
      Session ss=sf.openSession();

        Query q = ss.createQuery("FROM org.jasperreports.entitiy.User");

        List results = q.list();
        HashMap hm = new HashMap();
        hm.put("userId", ((User) results.get(1)).getUserId()); //or else hm.put("EmployeeId", args[o]);
        hm.put("userMessage",((User) results.get(1)).getUserMessage());// or else hm.put("EmployeeName", args[1]);
        hm.put("User_Name",((User) results.get(1)).getUserName());//or else 

        new JasperReportTest().generateReport(hm);

        System.exit(1);
        }
        }
```

Below is my .jrxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 5.6.2.final using JasperReports Library version 5.6.1  -->
<!-- 2014-10-15T20:22:18 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="959ae434-7516-46d9-a6ab-69e707496d67">
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
<parameter name="userId" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="userMessage" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="User_Name" class="java.lang.String"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="414" y="3" width="121" height="15" uuid="0cb2ba8e-4186-4173-8918-4b88c8b94af5"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[$P{userId}]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="3" width="136" height="15" uuid="e2ff7b5d-3a68-42a6-8160-15e3ef9f3e86"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[$P{userMessage}]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="200" y="3" width="136" height="15" uuid="22f30ae2-bc4a-4885-892b-7260c4d94474"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[$P{User_Name}]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="125" splitType="Stretch"/>
</detail>
<columnFooter>
    <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
</columnFooter>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageFooter>
<summary>
    <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
</summary>
</jasperReport>
```

I am not so familiar with the API here so I assumed that the keys that we are putting into the hashmap automatically maps to the column headers fields I created in the .jasper file and insert the corresponding values under them.

When I run the program it is generating an empty pdf file. Can anyone help me find the problem here.

** Note : The .jasper file i am using as input file is an empty file that only contains column header fields.